# Optional Parameters in C# Functionality

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am very confused and fustraded with the Optional parameters in C#
I am trying to accomplish the same I used to do with C++ and VB if the parameter is not necessary why bother to pass it, I am using the following within my functions below, but I when I the function, it still requires to pass something as parameter.
Is there a way that If the optional parameter is not needed to be passed to skip it and just pass the necessary parameters?

```
public static void WindowTOpen(string pUrl2Open, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue("")] string pWinName, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(0)] int pWidth, [Optional,        DefaultParameterValue(0)] int pHeight, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue("")] string pWinParams, object sender, System.Web.UI.Page pHtmlPage)
    {   
        //- Default to Page Display Minimun Size 800 x 600
        if (pWidth == 0) { pWidth = 800; } 
        if (pHeight == 0) { pHeight = 600; }
        if (pWinName.Trim().Length == 0) { pWinName = "NeWin"; }            
        string _WINDOW_TO_OPEN = "window.open(" + _sDOUBLE_QUOTE + pUrl2Open.Trim() + _sDOUBLE_QUOTE + "," + _sDOUBLE_QUOTE;            
        _WINDOW_TO_OPEN += pWinName.Trim() + _sDOUBLE_QUOTE + "," + _sDOUBLE_QUOTE + " width=" + pWidth.ToString() + ",";
        _WINDOW_TO_OPEN += "height=" + pHeight.ToString();
        if (pWinParams.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            _WINDOW_TO_OPEN += pWinParams.Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            _WINDOW_TO_OPEN += _WIN_OPEN_PARAMS;
        }
        _WINDOW_TO_OPEN += _sDOUBLE_QUOTE + ")";
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((sender as Control), pHtmlPage.GetType(), "winpop", _WINDOW_TO_OPEN, true);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can achieve by making optional parameters. Here I give you simple example. you can use it in your own way in your requirement. For example

```
public void Fun1(string p1, int p2, string p3 = null, string p4 = "Test")
    {

    }
```

Please make a note option parameters would be always as last parameters. Above function can be called as any of 2 way.

```
 this.Fun1("Test1", 123);
 this.Fun1(p2:123, p1:"Test1");
```

Hope this will helpful for you. Please let me know if you have any doubt on it.

Comment: Thank you ManojKS, what I am trying to understand what is this for [Optional, DefaultParameterValue("")] then, because based on Microsoft knowledge base it should work but apparently it does not.